# why i am getting 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'paginate' filter_by in Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to paginate the subscribed_users for the client but i am getting an error that says :

```
cl = Client.query.filter_by(family='John').first()
cl.subscribed_users.paginate()
```

`AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'paginate'`

Here is my **models.py**

```
subscribers = db.Table(
    'clients_subscribed',
    db.Column('client_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('client.id', ondelete='CASCADE')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
)

class Client(db.Model):
    subscribed_users = db.relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=subscribers,
        backref=db.backref('user', passive_deletes=True, lazy='dynamic')
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`paginate()` is defined on `BaseQuery` which is a subclass of `Query` in `sqlalchemy`. When you perform queries on `flask-sqlalchemy` models paginate is available but `subscribed_users` is not a `flask-sqlalchemy` model therefore you can't call paginate on it because It doesn't have.
The solution is to change `db.Table` to a class as follow:

```
class Subscribers(db.Model):
    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('client.id'), primary_key=True))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True))

class Client(db.Model):
    subscribed_users = db.relationship(
        ...
        secondary=Subscribers,
        ...
```

Comment: So i need to compare object with object, if i am not wrong i've compared object with list !!, thanks dude it worked :) .